# Which MVC version Is .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am an absolute newbie in ASP.NET and .NET CORE. I am trying to learn ASP.NET. 
I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx )

I am following this tutorial here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html and trying to build an web app. My project.json file for this tutorial is shown below.

My biggest confusion is: Which MVC I am learning? is It MVC 5 or MVC 6 from this tutorial?

Truth is I am really confused with all the versions of ASP.NET 5, .NET Core, MVC 5 and MVC 6 etc. etc. Can anyone please clarify. Thank you in advance

*project.json file generated from this tutorial*

```js
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-MvcDemo-135cd950-d3cc-487f-987b-d9ff67812eeb",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "MvcDiagnostics": "5.2.3"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is MVC Core 1.0. More info can be found at

https://docs.asp.net

Comment: is it not mvc 5 or mvc 6? Is Core 1.0 higher than mvc 6? I am really confused.

Comment: @JayBabani MVC 5 only runs on the full .NET Framework (not .NET Core), so it's definitely not that. MVC 6 was renamed to MVC Core 1.0. MVC Core 1.0 can run on the full .NET Framework or on .NET Core.

Comment: Thank you.. so its MVC 6. Can i get some more info on this renaming from MVC 6 to MVC core 1.0?

Comment: @JayBabani it is named ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0, so is a new start and has nothing to do with previous ones. Forget about MVC 6 please.